# How to identify the ID / name / title of the misclassified text file with sci-kit learn

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, text-classification, naivebayes

I am buidling my own classifier for text classification but at the moment I am playing with sci-kit learn in order to figure out few things. I classified few of my text files using NB classifier. I am using 26 text files manually categorised into 2 categories, with each of the files being numbered between 01 - 26 (i.e. '01.txt' and so forth).

My code and results:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
import numpy as np
bunch = load_files('corpus')

split_pcnt = 0.75 
split_size = int(len(bunch.data) * split_pcnt)
X_train = bunch.data[:split_size]
X_test = bunch.data[split_size:]
y_train = bunch.target[:split_size]
y_test = bunch.target[split_size:]

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, HashingVectorizer, CountVectorizer

clf_1 = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                      ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
    ])

from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score, KFold
from scipy.stats import sem

def evaluate_cross_validation(clf, X, y, K):
    # create a k-fold croos validation iterator of k=5 folds
    cv = KFold(len(y), K, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
    # by default the score used is the one returned by score >>> method of the estimator (accuracy)
    scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=cv)
    print scores
    print ("Mean score: {0:.3f} (+/-{1:.3f})").format(np.mean(scores), sem(scores))

clfs = [clf_1]

for clf in clfs:
    evaluate_cross_validation(clf, bunch.data, bunch.target, 5)

[ 0.5  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.6]
Mean score: 0.460 (+/-0.040)

from sklearn import metrics

def train_and_evaluate(clf, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):

    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print "Accuracy on training set:"
    print clf.score(X_train, y_train)
    print "Accuracy on testing set:"
    print clf.score(X_test, y_test)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

    print "Classification Report:"
    print metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
    print "Confusion Matrix:"
    print metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)


train_and_evaluate(clf_1, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)

Accuracy on training set:
1.0

Accuracy on testing set:
0.714285714286

    Classification Report:
                 precision    recall  f1-score   support

              0       0.67      0.67      0.67         3
              1       0.75      0.75      0.75         4

    avg / total       0.71      0.71      0.71         7

    Confusion Matrix:
    [[2 1]
     [1 3]]
```

What I cannot figure out is how to identify the IDs of the misclassified files, to see which exact files are misclassified (e.g. '05.txt' and '23.txt'). Is this possible with sci-kit learn at all?

best,

guzdeh

Comment: Side note: you should probably partition data into training and test sets randomly, rather than based on position, unless you're positive they were numbered at random. Fortunately, scikit-learn has an [easy function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to use the attribute `filenames` of the [load_files](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html) result.

However you have two model training and evaluation cycles in your example code: one using CV and another using simple train-test split.

In the train-test split:

```
test_filenames = bunch.filenames[split_size:]
misclassified = (y_pred != y_test)
print test_filenames[misscalssified]
```

This answer does not assume that the text files are in alphabetical order or that all numbers are present.

Comment: Hey dukeboy, thanks for your help and for pointing out those two models. I split them into two separate approaches now. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `load_files` loads the text files in alphabetical order, all you need are the indices of the examples that were misclassified. This can be obtained via:

```
misclassified = np.where(y_pred != y_test)
print(misclassified)
```

at the end of your `train_and_evaluate` function. So if this prints, say `[1, 3, 7]`, files '01.txt', '03.txt', and '07.txt' were misclassified.

Comment: Hey, Dave. Thanks for your help. Load_files has an option that enables you to load files non-randomly, but the default parameter setting is set to shuffle. However, when I tested what happens with the random option it turned out that files are shuffled, but always in a same way. Go figure. Thanks again. :)